# when textfield:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: return NO on iPad iOS 9, it will crash

Tags: ios

I want to limit the length of the text of a UITextField, then I implement the UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string {
return textField.text.length + string.length < 20;}
```

On iPad and iOS 9, the keyboard will show three buttons on the left top corner of the keyboard. When the length of the text reaches the max number, the method will return NO. Firstly I tapped button 3, then button 1. Why crashed my app?

[My GUI image and buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8rjF.png)

Comment: What crashing error do you have?

Comment: You need to provide details about the crash. Update your question with the complete and exact error message and post the relevant code causing the crash.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


if ( textField.text.length + string.length > 20) {

    return NO;
}

if (range.location == 20) {

    return NO;
}

    return YES;


}
```

because when you are pressing `undo` or `redo` button then it will call `substringWithRange` and you are getting invalid range that's why your app is crashing!

you can check it better by putting breakpoints in your `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method. check value of `range` and `string` every time!

Comment: downvoter first try it. I have tested this code! and first try question and check it is crashing and then try my answer and it will not!!

Comment: thank you very much! Your code will crash sometimes, but your explanation helps me a lot. I finally solved this crash with code:`
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


if ( textField.text.length + string.length > 20) {

    return NO;
}

if (range.location + range.length > textField.text.length) {

    return NO;
}

    return YES;
}

`